# How can I populate nested different content inside v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, nested, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, populate

So, I want to create 20 expansion panels with a v-for loop that populate every expansion panel header with the name of every category that I fetch from my JSON. After that, I need to populate every expansion panel content with the content of every name array inside allItems. How can I populate the first expansion panel content with the names of response.data[0].allItems, the second with the names of response.data[1].allItems etc.
The result will be 20 expansion panels, with 20 different headers (that I fetched from response.data) and every expansion panel content will have **seperate** content (the 1st an array of 13 names, the 2nd with 8 names etc.).
The problem with my code is that I have the same content in every expansion panel content.

```
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-expansion-panel v-for="category in categories" :key="category.name">
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ category.name }}
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
    <template v-for="category in categories">
      <template v-for="item in category.allItems">
        <v-expansion-panel-content :key="item.id">
          {{ item.name }}
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </template>
    </template>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>

async mounted() {
await axios
  .get("/api/menu")
  .then(response => (this.categories = response.data))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.errored = true;
  })
  .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
```

JSON Image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRaT3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to loop a second time through the categories inside each expansion panel. Instead loop the category.allItems array from the category object you accessed in the first `v-for`. Here is an example:

```
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-expansion-panel v-for="category in categories" :key="category.name">
    <v-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ category.name }}
    </v-expansion-panel-header>
     <v-expansion-panel-content>
        <div v-for="item in category.allItems">
             {{ item.name }}
        <div>
     </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

I haven't tested this but try and let me know if it works.
This should fill each expansion panel content with `<div>`s that contain all the items in the respective category.